# thumbnail generator using php code so to take scrrenshot of webpages

Tags: php, web, gdi, screenshot, thumbnails

Actually I am running a wesite [www.webmaggu.com](http://webmaggu.com) which is mainly a directory of variou interesting links and websites which are submitted by users. I want to generate thumbnails beside the links. So tried webnapr, picoshot and many others but they don't give free thumbnails for longer days. so I want to generate my own thumbnail generator. I have seem various codes using IE capt on websites but I don't know why they are not working on my website [www.webmaggu.com](http://webmaggu.com)
Actually my hosting provider is linux based but they say they have GDI running on different servers which supports both linux and windows users...

so if any body can help with codes or some links .....

Answer (score 5):

Under windows it's pretty easy. You need to enable gd in your php.ini file. You do that by removing the ; on the follow line:

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

Then use the following code:

```
<?php
$ie = new COM("InternetExplorer.Application") or die("Unable to instanciate Internet Explorer");
$ie->Navigate2("http://www.digeshops.com");
$ie->Visible = true;
while ($ie->ReadyState!=4) usleep(200);
$handle = $ie->HWND;
$img = imagegrabwindow($handle);
$ie->Quit();
imagepng($img,"screenGrap.png");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a 100% standalone solution for taking screenshots of websites, there is a project called [khtml2png](http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/)

It requires no external webservice and renders a webpage using the Konquerer engine under Linux. it should be pretty easy to install, depending on your Linux server distro.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi shashank**

See something interesting here

**10 Free Website Thumbnail Generation Services**

http://www.neurosoftware.ro/wp/elvis/php/10-free-website-thumbnail-generation-services/

i will say , you to check http://www.thumbalizr.com/ coz there is api. using php you can generate and store info in db as if needed.

Some API based useful resource

- http://webshotspro.com/
- http://www.websnapr.com/
- http://webthumb.bluga.net/home
- http://quickthumbnail.com/

Comment: hey i have used a lot of services like picoshot, shrink the web....but after few days they all stop the service and start giving their site names...check it out at www.webmaggu.com .since i require a large amount of thumbnails so i thought of making my own..  even i used thumboo api. it is very good but i can't pu it in <img src code >i don't know why.http://www.webmaggu.com/webthumb/thumbnail.php?url=http://www.yahoo.com . this link doesn't produce any image under img

Comment: if you server support python, you can host some script and generate would be good.

Comment: yeah my server supports python ... I also want to use some scripts and generate my thumbnails on my own.... btw japan pro i thnk u have worked a lot in web desigining ...seems to be a n expert..

Comment: thats great , see this link http://lapin-blanc.net/09/11/2008/django-website-thumbnail-generator/. Ya i have been working since many years not its time to contribute.

Comment: if you find info use full accept or voteup to your matched answer, i am suggestion as you are new to stackoverflow.

Comment: ok.yeah i have seen this link.. the problem with this link is that it requires to install djano on my webhost server. since i am on shared server so i can't install it...well search is going on..btw stackoverflow is nice i have lots of questions in my mind...will post soon...

Comment: you can accept as solution , hance you will get some point as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a freeware hosted on your Linux.

For example (googled it) : http://code.google.com/p/webthumb/

It uses Mozilla for generating thumbnails.

Good Luck !

Comment: vinzius ...this one is good but i want it live on my website and not through any software....

Comment: You just need to call the software from PHP... I don't think you will find a method with PHP without using an other website. Good Luck.

Comment: yeah that is a good solution indeed but problem is when u require it in large amount .... u will have to go for premium version....and i m not in that state to pay for premium accounts..will be searching for some codes....will post here if i find some good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned above that you can't install djano on your shared hosting account, which probably means you can't install any of the solutions mentioned here, let alone install something you've written yourself.

The way I see it you have 2 solutions:

1) With a bit of hacking you could create the thumbnails automatically on your home PC, and FTP them to your hosting account.

2) Read the Terms of Use for the free services you're using. There's a good chance they're blocking you. I'd suggest caching the thumbnails locally, and serving them from your server instead of hot linking them.